Swift UIKit UICalendarView inside the UIScrollView
I'm creating a screen similar to this, my problem is that the calendar remains fixed at the top, how can I put the UICalendarView inside the UIScrollView to make it scroll vertically?


So I have a scrollview and inside a calendar with a tableview underneath.

Please add some code relating to adding calendar view inside scroll view ?

Please check https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KHfsyRHRsl5jnJNK7eDfI6RPnDY9qKw8/view?usp=sharing we can able to scroll with calendar view, just check that your scroll view's content view is height is proper

I solved it like this: I put it inside a UIView and the UIView inside the UIScrollView, now it works. Thanks.

let calendarView = UICalendarView()
IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
IBOutlet weak var calendarViewContainer: UIView!
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
calendarViewContainer.addSubview(calendarView)

calendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
calendarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: calendarViewContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 21).isActive = true
calendarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: calendarViewContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -21).isActive = true
calendarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: calendarViewContainer.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
calendarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 430).isActive = true
